# Drupal programmatic view block output fault

Tags: php, view, drupal

I am attempting to load some pages within my latest dynamically via AJAX.

To this end, I am experimenting with load my views generated block programmatically. By default, the block contains images carouselling around using the views slideshow plugin.

I am using the following code snippet:

```
<?php
        $view       =   'pagetopimage';
        $block_id   =   'block_1';
        $args       =   array(32);
        print views_embed_view( $view, $block_id, $args );
    ?>
```

Using the code above, the block gets printed but the carouselling effect is broken. How might I fix this?

Comment: you probably need to include a JS too (assuming your carouselling uses JS ..)

Comment: Very correct remy, but I need some information on what JS file and how to programmatically include it ???

Comment: First, I would recommend disabling JS compression under performance settings. Then navigate to a page where the carousel is working properly and take note of all the JS files being loaded on the page. Then navigate to your page that is not working, compare those JS files and identify the missing JS file(s). Then make sure those missing JS file(s) are being loaded on your page that will be using AJAX.

Comment: Thanks @tyler.frankenstein, using your tip I was able to identify a missing JS file. Would anyone know how to dynamically load a JS file? Especially one that belongs to a module in a Drupal website ???

Comment: Please checkout the drupal_add_js function and the answer from @rémy to see a general use case.

Answer (score 1):

to load the file when it's in the modules place, use:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'your_module_name') .'/daFile.js');
```

to load in general (starting from the install root), use:

```
drupal_add_js('misc/ajax.js');
```

[drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) is very powerful, see yourself ..

Comment: your suggestion is valid and I tried it but it didn't work. Without attempting to include JS scripts programmatically, I get the following error : Drupal.settings.viewsSlideshowSingleFrame is undefined !?!?